# Get caret XY coordinates in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, caret

Is there any good JQuery/JS solution to get the absolute position of a caret in text area (given in X/Y coordinates OR top/left coordinates). 
The native Event object of keyDown JQuery function gives the x/y coordinates of the cursor and I want something similar the works on the working caret.

 
My goal is to add a floating HTML element the will be positioned relatively to the working caret position so I need to somehow get its position.

I need the solution to work on TextArea elements but a general solution to any editable html element would be even better!

Comment: u cnt but there is something that gives u the number of characters to the left

Comment: @OrShachar: Have you used the plugin mentioned in the answer below? has it worked for all the editable controls in html?

Comment: Unfortunately it was so long ago that I don't remember .But from my reaction it seems like it did.

Answer (score 6):

may be you want replace `<textarea>` with `<div contenteditable="true">`, it has almost the same behavior, and you can get coordinates by conventional way.

Comment: Thanks ! My even more general idea is to create a Chrome extension that works to every content editable element in the page so I have to know all the ways to do it. What is the conventional way to do it with div?

Comment: that's only one crossbrowser way i know, may be chrome has something special, i don't know.

Comment: @ValentinKantor What is the way? I am looking for that now.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow add the `contenteditable="true"` to your div

Comment: @ValentinKantor Thanks. And then grab the x,y offset of a zero-width unicode character wrapped in a span inserted at the caret position.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow nice logic :)

Comment: @CrisStringfellow how do you find the zero-width unicode character wrapped in a span? I've tried to print out contenteditable divs content, but it does not show the caret.